# Wordpress, get links to Custom Content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom content and I need to have links that go to the next post.

I am currently using this two methods:

previous_post_link( '%link', '' . _x( '←', 'Previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . ' %title' );

next_post_link( '%link', '%title ' . _x( '→', 'Next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' );

But the problem is these methods go only 1 up and 1 down. I need something that is going to give all the post links. is there such a method?

Comment: When you say custom content, do you mean a custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method. You'll have to create a custom solution like so:

http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/better-wordpress-pagination/

Or do a search for "pagination" in the Wordpress plug-ins repository. There are several plug-ins that will suit your needs immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://yourwebsitehere.com/?paged=YourNumberHere
```

So long as your templates are using the $paged variable to paginate your queries. Then you can use this link to implement pagination, if your post is a custom post type you can do it like

```
http://yourwebsitehere.com/?paged=YourNumberHere&post_type=YourPostType
```

With this you can create an interface like

```
<a href="http://yourwebsitehere.com/?paged=YourNumberHere">1</a>
<a href="http://yourwebsitehere.com/?paged=YourNumberHere">2</a>
<a href="http://yourwebsitehere.com/?paged=YourNumberHere">3</a>
<a href="http://yourwebsitehere.com/?paged=YourNumberHere">4</a>
<a href="http://yourwebsitehere.com/?paged=YourNumberHere">5</a>
```

And so on and so on.

But paginate links does kind of the same thing... and it has a ton of arguments to get whatever you need just read the codex on it.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links